# Make transparent background in xml

Tags: android, camera

I have android scanner project and its totally working to me .I ask and search a lot but it is not the thing that i want.  What i want to do is to make my layout background Transparent like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFovP.png

They suggest to me to use :

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

but what happen is it just make my background White(#ffff), you can see here in this picture https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCkoi.jpg my backgroud is Blue but what I'm trying to do is the first picture above .

Thank you in advance for the answer.

Comment: Note: My background is like a Camera preview.

Answer (score 0):

If your xml Layout Background is Transparent it's Still not enough to make the Background of an Activity Transparent. You Need to Add these to your Style:

```js
<style name="Transparent" parent = "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   ...
   
  <item name = "android:windowIsTranslucent"> true </item> 
  <item name = "android:windowBackground"> @color / transparent </item>
   ...

</style>
```

Comment: hey Joshua, You want the Background to Be A Camera View??

Comment: How Is your CameraView's Height and Width??

Comment: if you can see the first link above it show transparent background right? and if you can see the second link i have blue background.. i want to make it like the first picture above

Comment: I use FrameLayout to show the camera... Height 150dp width is 150dp also

Comment: Well I Saw It, But If The Blue thingy is your Background It must be Transparent Right Now, What Is that Blue Color? Is it a Layout?

Comment: That is my probem i want to make it Transparent like the first pic above

Comment: ALright, First, Your FrameLayout, Which is Your Camera View, Make The Height and Width Of them 'Match_Parent'.  Then Go to your Blue LinearLayout XML, And SetAlpha to something Like (0.5).   THEN, See the Results, And Post it if you Can Please

Comment: Also, Make sure Blue LinearLayout Is in Front of CameraView, You can give it an Elevation Value

Comment: sorry, it would be much easier to help if you provided your Styles and Layouts as well. I hope someone else can help you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48615762/how-to-add-redline-in-camera-preview/48615941#48615941 check my last post i provided all here